# Store jquery .click as a cookie

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, themes

Afternoon and thanks in advance to those who fancy having a go at this.

I have a client who has changed their requirements slightly and now wishes to add something to their site.

I have used jquery .click to change lots of css on a site to provide different levels of accessibility to those with sight problems.

This is the site, the color changer is at the top.
http://www.dsndev.dewinterdev.co.uk

```
<div id="colour-scheme">
<p>
    Colour Scheme <span class="default"><button onclick="reloadPage()">A</button></span>
    <span class="white"><button>A</button></span>
    <span class="yellow"><button>A</button></span>
</p>
```

This is the code `http://jsfiddle.net/ZNuWg/

I want to store the information a a cookie so that when the user clicks the button, they can return to the site with the correct colour scheme active.

Comment: Sorry, but that is a really horrible hard-wired way to change themes. Just change a single class at the top of the DOM (body? HTML? etc) and do it all via CSS. If you move your existing CSS files to use LESS then it becomes very to manage even very deep CSS hierarchies.

Comment: Its the same old story of had things been a little clearer from the beginning it may have been different. This is also my first time using jquery and im slowly picking things up. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1: and now you have 15 rep.. welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst to remedy your situation regarding the click and cookie is simple, note I have abstracted the code to do all the changes to a separate function(s) to allow reusabilty, I would perhaps move all the css changes to 2 separate css files and load them instead of doing all the javascript.  I have included the jQuery cookie plugin from here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/ZNuWg/2/

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".white button").click(function(){setWhite()});
    jQuery(".yellow button").click(function(setYellow()});

    //Do the cookie check 
    //Check color cookie value
    if (jQuery.cookie('color') == 'White') {
        setWhite();
    } else if (jQuery.cookie('color') == 'Yellow') {
        setYellow();
    }


    function setWhite() {
        //First set the cookie
        jQuery.cookie('color', 'White');

        //jQuery(".top-bar").css("border-bottom","0px solid #189AC2");
        //social links
        jQuery(".menu-logo img").attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/logo-white.png');
        jQuery(".logo img").attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/logo-white.png');
        jQuery(".facebook").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery(".twitter").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery(".pintrest").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery(".youtube").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery(".linkedin").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery(".google").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-white.png)");
        jQuery("#bslvideoshow").css("background", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/bsl-video.png) repeat scroll 0 center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        //latest news section
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("color", "#189AC2");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #189AC2");
        jQuery("#latest-news h3").css("color", "#189AC2");
        jQuery("#latest-news p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news a").css("color", "#189AC2");
        //twitter section
        jQuery("#index-twitter").css("background-image", "url(wp-content/themes/dsn/images/twitter-white.png)");
        jQuery("#index-twitter").css("background-size", "85% auto");
        jQuery("#index-twitter p").css("color", "#ffffff");
        jQuery("#index-twitter iframe").css("margin-left", "54px");
        //footer & copyright
        jQuery(".top-bar-full p").css("color", "");
        jQuery("#controls a").css("color", "");
        jQuery(".copyright ul li").css("border-right", "");
        //footer-section
        jQuery(".footer").css("border-top", "");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid h2").css("color", "");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid h3").css("color", "");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("border-bottom");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid").css("color", "");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid p").css("color", "");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid a").css("color", "");
        //forms
        jQuery("#search button").css("background", "");
        jQuery("#keep-in-touch button").css("background", "");
        jQuery(".stayconnectedright i").css("background", "");
        //main-menu
        jQuery(".index-menu li").css("border", "none");
        jQuery(".index-menu li").css("padding", "57px 0");
        jQuery(".index-menu a").css("background", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu li a").css("border", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu a").css("border", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu").css("background", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu a").css("color", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu").css("border", "");
        jQuery(".the-content p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".the-content h2").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".sub-menu-wrap").css("background", "#ffffff");
        jQuery(".sub-menu-wrap span").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".download-module a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".section-title").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".section-title").css("border-top", "1px solid #000");
        jQuery(".main-menu li").css("background", "");
        jQuery(".menu-item-389").css("border", "");
        jQuery(".content-navigation ul li").css("border", "");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".title").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("border-bottom", "1px solid#000");
        jQuery("#latest-news a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".the-content a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".the-content a").css("text-decoration", "underline");
        jQuery(".sd-title").css("color", "#000 !important");
        jQuery(".the-date").css("color", "#fff");
        jQuery(".archive-nav a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".archive-nav a:hover").css("font-weight", "bold");
        jQuery(".archive-nav").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #000");
        jQuery(".footer").css("border-top", "none");
        jQuery(".content-navigation li a").css("color", "#fff");
        //top and bottom background colours
        var bodyclass = $('body').attr('class');
        jQuery(".top-bg-white").addClass(bodyclass);
        jQuery(".bottom-bg-white").addClass(bodyclass);
        jQuery("body").css("background", "none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF");
        jQuery(".madeby").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".post-board p").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".post-board a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".post-board a").css("text-decoration", "underline");
        jQuery(".the-date p").css("color", "#fff");
        jQuery(".madeby").css("color", "#fff");
        jQuery(".archive-nav ul li").css("background", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/bullet-keyline1.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        jQuery(".archive-nav .current-menu-item").css("background", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/bullet-keyline.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        jQuery(".top-bg-yellow").css("display", "");
        jQuery(".bottom-bg-yellow").css("display", "");
        jQuery(".footer-logos img").attr("src", "");
    }

    function setYellow() {

        //First set the cookie
        jQuery.cookie('color', 'Yellow');

        jQuery("body").css("background", "none repeat scroll 0 0 #f7e463");
        jQuery(".top-bg-yellow").css("display", "block");
        jQuery(".bottom-bg-yellow").css("display", "block");
        jQuery(".menu-logo img").attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/logo-yellow.png");
        //social links
        jQuery(".logo img").attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/logo-yellow.png');
        jQuery(".facebook").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery(".twitter").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery(".pintrest").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery(".youtube").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery(".linkedin").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery(".google").css("background-image", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/social-widget-yellow.png)");
        jQuery("#bslvideoshow").css("background", "url(/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/bsl-video-yellow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        //latest news section
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news h3").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news a").css("color", "#000000");
        //twitter section
        jQuery("#index-twitter").css("background-image", "url(wp-content/themes/dsn/images/twitter-yellow.png)");
        //footer-section
        jQuery(".footer").css("border-top", "1px solid #000000");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid h2").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid h3").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#latest-news h2").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #000000");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery("#bottom-grid a").css("color", "#000000");
        //top bar
        jQuery(".top-bar a").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".top-bar p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".top-bar").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #000000");
        //forms
        jQuery("#search button").css("background", "#000000");
        jQuery("#keep-in-touch button").css("background", "#000000");
        jQuery(".stayconnectedright i").css("background", "#000000");
        //main-menu
        jQuery(".index-menu li ").css("background", "#F7E463");
        jQuery(".index-menu li ").css("border", "10px solid #000000");
        jQuery(".index-menu li").css("padding", "");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu").css("border", "0px");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu li").css("border", "0px");
        jQuery(".index-menu .sub-menu-wrap").css("background", "#F7E463");
        jQuery(".index-menu a").css("color", "#000");
        //content navigation
        jQuery(".main-menu li").css("background", "#F7E463");
        jQuery(".content-navigation ul li").css("border", "3px solid #000");
        jQuery(".sub-menu-wrap ul li").css("border", "none");
        jQuery(".menu-item-389").css("border", "none");
        jQuery("ul li a").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".the-content p").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".the-content h2").css("color", "#000000");
        jQuery(".sub-menu-wrap").css("background", "#F7E463");
        jQuery(".sub-menu-wrap span").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".download-module a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".section-title").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".section-title").css("border-top", "1px solid #000");
        jQuery("h3").css("color", "#000000");
        //copyright
        jQuery(".copyright ul li").css("border-right", "1px solid #000000");
        jQuery(".footer-logos img").attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/dsn/images/logos-yellow.png");
        jQuery(".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit").css("background", "none repeat scroll 0 0 #000");
        jQuery(".the-content a").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".the-content a").css("text-decoration", "underline");
        jQuery(".title").css("color", "#000");
        jQuery(".default button").css("border", "1px solid #000");
        jQuery(".madeby").css("color", "#000");
    }
});
```

Comment: Love that youve taken the time to help me here. Im new to the plugin you have suggested, would I need to do much other than add the script to my site and then use your code above or are there other options and code i need to consider from the instructions on github?

Comment: note: The click handlers shown are broken. They should not call the function, they should just pass the function.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Of course!   Silly me! Will update code

Comment: @AlexKnopp No you can just include the script available on github which is jquery.cookie.js after you include jquery on your page and then the above code should do the trick. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Ok brilliants this has worked so well. The most common pages on the site will be shown in exactly the right way that the user needs. However, can I ask, is there a way to set this kind of cookie to apply to every page on the site?

Comment: This should work on all pages.  Perhaps incorporate @TrueBlueAussie 's answer and then add the code somewhere in your shared header so that all pages automatically get the cookie and you can add all color specific css to the one css file.

Comment: Hi Rob, although this does work on all pages, the cookie is not loaded on all pages. I dont have the resources to be able to go back to the drawing board on this one. Is anyone able to tell me how I can store this cookie and use it globally. Perhaps to load it from my head. Sorry if I sounds totally newbie on this one. Thanks

Comment: Alex, the cookie code must be included on every page, also make sure you are using the `path` variable correctly https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#path to make sure it is available across the whole domain.

Comment: Its a wordpress website and is included in my wp_head(); tag so is available on all pages. Its just doesnt seem to work when you navigate to another page where the cookie hasnt been set.

Comment: have you looked at setting the path variable to the root of the domain as mentioned earlier?  Failing that, perhaps you can link the site and we can take a look at what's going on.

Comment: Ok. So ive finally got all this. What a total balls up Ive made of this. Having said that its been a massive learning curve for me into js and cookies alike. I know where I went wrong and Ive got my head around knowing what to do next time. Just want to say a thanks to all of you. THe cookie works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would suggest you approach dynamic themes, rather than hard-coding changes:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLn4a/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="colour-scheme">
    <p>Colour Scheme 
    <span class="default"><button>default</button></span>
    <span class="white"><button>White</button></span>
    <span class="yellow"><button>Yellow</button></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

### jQuery just changes a class on body element

```
$(function () {
    $('#colour-scheme').on('click', 'button', function () {
        $('body').removeClass('default white yellow').addClass($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
});
```

This code just takes the `class` from the parent of the button and adds it to the `body` element.

### CSS (specific to each hierarchy):

```
body.default {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
body.white {
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
}
body.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: green;
}
```

This moves the styling maintenance where it belongs (into styles).

### Cookies:

You could just restore your cookie value as a class name into the `body` element on load:

e.g.  `$('body').addClass(cookieValue);`

Which all together becomes:

```
$(function () {
    var cookieValue = getMyCookieValueCodeHere;
    $('body').addClass(cookieValue);
    $('#colour-scheme').on('click', 'button', function () {
        $('body').removeClass('default white yellow').addClass($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
});
```

### Early setting:

You probably want the theme `class` to be set on the page as soon as the page begins to load. You can do this with raw javascript in the page `head` (jQuery is not ready at that time).

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    // read cookie value with raw javascript
    document.body.className += cookievalue;
</script>
```

### Optional "default" theme:

Your "default" theme does not need to use the class (e.g. default) but is simply any base CSS without any `body.class` selector. i.e. your current original CSS.

Comment: *You can lead a horse to water... hold its head under for 10 minutes... but it still... won't... drink!* :)

Comment: Thanks for the dtailed instruction. Ill save this and use this again. but I don't really have time to go back to the drawing board on this one. Is there a way to get and set the cookie and load it globally so that the user can set it on the home page and use it throughout the site. I'm using Rob Schmuecker's answer. Thanks.

Comment: Re "I don't really have time": you will spend more time in the long run doing it in code (and have more bugs that way). Re cookies: Of course, that's what cookies are for. They are global to the site by default. You need to ask a  new question if you want specifics. PS. *the up arrow buttons are for thanks on SO* :)

Comment: If the cookie is global to the site by default then how it is that it only seems to work one page at a time? I understand that I should have done this properly from the beginning but time really is against me now. Much of my learning has been my making some mistakes and Ive learned that i need to do this properly but in future.

Comment: As I said about cookies "You need to ask a new question if you want specifics". PS. the up arrow buttons are still for thanks on SO (and you now have a 15 rep so can use them) :)